# Including additional CC fields in Order Confirmation emails

Tags: orders, email, email-templates

Google hasn't been able to solve this one for me and I'm surprised it hasn't been brought up in Magento forums...

I would like to include the credit card type and last 4 of credit card as stored in Magento's *Payment Information* area for each order. Trying to alleviate confusion for our end-users and make the emails more informative. How would I begin to include these two fields? Thank you.

Comment: It's not fine to get the credit card information, if you have the credit card info then you have all access of card. this is only happen if you have your own payment method.

Comment: This is payment information that Magento does in fact store by default. The last 4 of the CC number and the card type (MC, AMEX, Visa, Discover). I want to present that in an email to the customer. This is the same type of payment validation as seen on other PCI compliant shopping carts/sites.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using this code:

```
$order->getPayment()->getCcLast4();
```

Comment: Testing this now. Will let you know!

Comment: Thank you. That is the correct reference which ultimately led to the discovery of how to implement: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23798073/how-to-get-all-order-details-including-payment-custmer-and-shipping-details-from

Comment: Glad to know, that you task is accomplished

Answer (score 1):

Please refer to similar questions answered here before

[Magento Payment Info Block](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9167831/magento-payment-info-block)

[Saving extra data with an order in Magento](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4370235/saving-extra-data-with-an-order-in-magento)

Comment: I will test this solution and confirm that it solves my problem. Thank for you the links!